# Text parse using awk or sed in UNIX. Extract a port number

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have to extract a certain port number piped from a process status (ps) command and am not quite sure how to get it.

For example, if I had this line (ps -ef | grep "blahblahblah"):

```
xxremote -xcom.xx.management.xremote.port=9999 -xcom.xx.management.xxxremote.ssl=false
```

How can I extract the number    "9999"? NOTE: This is one part of a very LONG line, and I cannot use, for example, awk, to count  how many fields after the "=" sign. The number of = signs will change.

I tried using the cut command but I only know how to use it with single character delimiters which isn't what I need. I was thinking maybe awk or sed would do the trick? I am not to familiar with them. Thank you very much for the help

ps -ef | grep "blahblahblah" " | awk   ....        (or sed)

**UPDATE:** Clarified that the port number needs to be extracted form a single long line of text, and that using an awk command is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps -ef | sed -n '/blahblahblah/s/^.*port=\([[:digit:]]\+) .*/\1/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

(**updated** to filter only lines that contain `xremote.port=` in case the data isn't filtered yet)

```
ps -elf | awk -F= '/xremote.port=/{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}'
```

The first `awk` command splits the line on `=` resulting in the 2nd field being:

```
9999 -xcom.xx.management.xxxremote.ssl
```

the second `awk` command grabs the first field of this which is your number.

```
9999
```

Comment: no need for two AWKs. Use `split()` or `-F '[ =]'`. What if the arguments are in a different order and `$2` isn't the right one?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson With the `-F '[ =]'` I still have to specify the field to get the number, in this case `$3`. I used 2 awks because I build the answer incrementally, reflection of habit, and perhaps an indication there's more about awk for me to learn :)

Comment: If the selection of text I am pulling from is much larger, how can I use the awk command to pull the port based on "xremote.port="

Comment: The OP probably means that you need a selector `awk '/xremote.port=/{...}'`

Comment: @user1518487 If your question was on how to find the lines that contain `xremote.port=` then what DennisWilliamson posted above is the standard way in `awk` to find specific lines in the input (thanks Dennis) and you would put it with the first `awk` command. From the original post I assumed the lines were already filtered to contain only those strings - if not, then this will catch them.

Comment: Yes my question was on this. Sorry for the confusion, but my issue, is that the selection is from a large block of text, NOT separated into lines, so using cut or awk and counting the number of fields is not ideal because there could be variance the number of fields its counting. 

Again, to clarify, there is a large block of text, NOT separated by lines. So if `awk '/xremote.port=/` is run, the entire block of code is displayed. If i use 
`|cut -d "=" -f6,6` I believe it works but again, if the placement of "=" changes, it doesnt work probably Thank you @Levon and @Dennis Williamson

Comment: @user1518487: I don't understand what you mean by a block that's not separated into lines. That's contradictory. It's either one line or multiple lines. Sometimes a multi-line record is referred to as a "block".

Comment: @DennisWilliamson. You are right, It is one extremely long line.

Comment: @user1518487 .. and I'm a bit confused to since you specifically asked for an `awk` solution, but now say "so using cut or awk and counting the number of fields is not ideal".

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This was my first post.
Thank you so much for the help! You guys are great. 
I'll be sure to make a more thorough post next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Must you use Awk? `sed` would be a better choice...

Oh well...

```
ps -ef | awk '/blahblahblah/ {
    sub(".*port=", "")
    sub(" .*", "")
    print $0
}'
```

The `sub(a, b)` command in awk substitutes the regular expression `a` with string `b` (which happens to be blank in my case. It takes $0 which represents the line returned.

As I said, `sed` would be simpler:

```
ps -ef | sed -n '/blahblahblah/s/^.*port=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'
```

Notice I'm using `sed` to select the line *blahblahblah* and to do the substitution.

Comment: Actually I can use `sed`. This is the output when I run the sed command:      
'9999
\([^'
    Any idea why I am getting those extra characters on the end?

Comment: I just ran this: `echo "xxremote -xcom.xx.management.xremote.port=9999 -xcom.xx.management.xxxremote.ssl=false" | sed -n 's/^.*port=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p'` and got `9999` with nothing on the end. Do you have the same issue with Dennis William's answer. We basically had similar `sed` statements. He was using Gnu's `sed` which allows for some neat tricks, and I used the one that Solaris has.